# Anaconda Jupyter notebook cannot connect to kernel "connection failed"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am using anaconda Jupyter notebook for class. However, when I tried to open the folder shared with us, I get the error of "connection failed", and no one else in the class seem to be experiencing the same problem.

This is what it says after loading for a while:

[image: this is what it says after loading for a while]

I tried re-install anaconda for a few time, and followed a lot of the commands I found on the forum, but the issue persists.

Lastly, I updated the notebook to the newest version, and the error message now says "error starting kernel".

Which I believe is the same problem as the previous version:

[image: which I believe is the same problem as the previous version]
It also says "kernel unknown"

Although I even downloaded a separate one on my own:

[image: although I even downloaded a separate one on my own]

I am using windows 11 laptop, and anaconda runs all fine on my old computer (also win11).

Will anyone be able to help with this? And, if possible, would you be kind to provide the instructions as if you are speaking to a five-year-old as I am very new to this.

Many, many thanks in advance! and sorry for posting this well-known error, but none of the available answers to this issue works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First it is optional (yet suggested) to create a separate environment (not the base/root) this can be done with the anaconda navigator or from inside the anaconda prompt. Then make sure that the required packages are installed

1. Open the anaconda prompt.
2. Activate the desired environment with `activate <ENVIRONMENT_NAME>`
3. Run `pip install jupyter ipykernel`

In order to run python notebooks you need an interactive python kernel (ipykernel). List the existing kernels by running `jupyter kernelspec list`.

If then you want to create an ipykernel do the following:

1. `ipython kernel install --user --name=<NAME> --display-name="<DISPLAY_NAME>"`

The DISPLAY_NAME will appear at your last pictured.

Finally, open jupyter by running `jupyter notebook` and at the top right select `New` to create a new notebook there select the kernel you created.

If you are still having problems let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much! A separate environment solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps and see what happens:
1 - Try to restart your laptop and try to reopen the Jupyter Notebook again.
2 - Try to install a new environment ( You can install it from Anaconda) instead of using Anaconda Prompt. it is the same.
3 - It could be the working directory is not set to be directed to the shared file. follow this steps:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()  # Prints the current working directory
```

then Change the working directory to the shared file usin f this code:

```
os.chdir('c:\\Users\\uname\\desktop\\python')  # Provide the new path here
```

Finally, and probably this is the reason is that your access to the shared file is not setup correctly. You should contact your administrator to check on your access to the shared file.

These steps should fix your problem.

Comment: Installing a separate environment was enough for me! Thank you very much for all the information!